# How to get data validation list options array?

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a html template to automate Google Sheets. How can I get an array of values that appears in data validation list?

I tried all methods from `DataValidation`... but all I can get is `[Range, true]` array. Is there any method to list all valid options like `[option_1, option_2, option_3]`?

```
function getOptions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ubMapaDrrOySpreadSheetIDjBEvHxphA83rzs')
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet_name");
  var dv = sheet.getRange(2, 19).getDataValidation()
  var myTarget = dv.getCriteriaValues();
  Logger.log(myTarget)
}
```

I expect an array of options: `[option1, option2, option3, etc..]`, but I get an array with two elements: `[range, true]`.

Comment: Note that the return value of `getCriteriaValues()` is dependent on the type of the data validation. Probably yours is "Require value in range, allow invalid". Thus, the `Range` with values is given, and the parameter specifying whether invalid values are allowed. The intended use of `getCriteriaValues()` is, per documentation, to allow creating DataValidation from criteria: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation#getcriteriavalues

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution, with Cooper's tip, so I can enter it by myself.
All I had to do, was to get values from first argument of array returned from method getCriteriaValues(). Theres no getValues command prompted by editor, but when I entered it manually, I got expected array.

```
function getOptions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ubMapaDrrOySpreadSheetIDjBEvHxphA83rzs')
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet_name");
  var dv = sheet.getRange(2, 19).getDataValidation();
  var critVal = dv.getCriteriaValues();
  var myTarget = critVal[0].getValues();
  Logger.log(myTarget)
}
```

And voile :).

Answer (score 0):

I was working on another problem looking for the rule that applied to a certain data validation range.  [This is a link to that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128164/7215091).  In my case I found in this area of the code:
`var args=rule.getCriteriaValues();
            if(args[0].getA1Notation()==org.getA1Notation()) {`

That args[0] was infact the range object.  I hope that might be of some help to you.

Comment: It helps a lot by directing my research. Thank you. What I had to do, was to getValues from first argument of returned array: (range). This getValues function does not appear in args[0].code suggestions, but when I enter it manually, it starts to work! Love you Cooper!

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a clarification to the above code by Radoslaw, which is fantastic and was the key to solving my issue with this general topic.

I needed to get a list of options and split it as an array, where each element needs to be a validation criteria for the automated assignment of options in a range. Particularly, the "getValues()" method errored out in my case, and I used the "toString()" method, and then its split method to get what I needed. Particularly:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("New Leads")
  var dv = ss.getRange(2, 7).getDataValidation();
  var critVal = dv.getCriteriaValues();
  var myTarget = critVal[0].toString();

  //split the string into individual entries by comma
  var nameArr = myTarget.split(',');

  //get the divisor for the number of people to assign 
  var numNames = nameArr.length

  for(int i=0; i<numNames; i++) {

     Logger.log(nameArr[i]);

  }
```

I hope this also helps someone, and it worked for me.